# How to launch term at startup in Emacs?

Tags: init-file, eshell, start-up, term

I need to have Emacs open a terminal at start-up automatically (in order to use Fish in the terminal and use Emacs to for example search the Fish output).

Normally I do this with 'M-x term'.

Is there a way to make Emacs do this?

I tried adding `(term)` and `(eshell)` (as an alternative) in many combinations such as this one:

```
 1 (visual-line-mode 1)
  2 (global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
  3 (scroll-bar-mode -1)
  4 (tool-bar-mode -1)
  5 (menu-bar-mode -1)
  6
  7 (require 'package)
  8 (let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
  9                     (not (gnutls-available-p))))
 10        (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
 11
 12   (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
 13   ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
 14   (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
 15     ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
 16     (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "gnu" (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
 17 (package-initialize)
 18
 19 (custom-set-variables
 20  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 21  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 22  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 23  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 24  '(custom-safe-themes
 25    (quote
 26     ("123dcd41949ac04ccbe3cab4caadec7bf0e01a6f85ffa23ff02c4102529b57dd" "53ba7affc1a77f85b89bb54bcc9fee688bab35d413db6309adfeca1890874395" "59e82a683db7129c0142b4b5a3\
    5dbbeaf8e01a4b81588f8c163bd255b76f4d21" default)))
 27  '(package-selected-packages (quote (cyberpunk-theme))))
 28 (custom-set-faces
 29  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 30  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 31  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 32  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 33  )
 34
 35 (add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (load-theme 'cyberpunk)))
 36
 37 (with-eval-after-load 'org
 38   (setq org-startup-indented t) ; Enable `org-indent-mode' by default
 39   (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode)
 40   (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'eshell))
 41
 42 (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'eshell)
```

This still opens nothing but the main screen anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Start with Eshell:

```el
(setq initial-buffer-choice #'eshell)
```

Start with running Bash in Term:

```el
(setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda () (term "bash")))
```

`C-h v initial-buffer-choice`

> If the value is a function, call it with no arguments and switch to
>   the buffer that it returns.

Comment: Sorry, this does nothing too… The first and second one changed nothing and even when I saved the init.el with both of them together they still changed nothing.

Comment: @FusedEmacs-confused You need to understand the variable `initial-buffer-choice` and some understanding of Emacs Lisp, it makes no sense to put them both to your init file since only the second will take effect.

Comment: Thank you, the second does not take effect (like I had said).